# Rails4: Private Pub over HTTPS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, https, private-pub

I'm doing an app which uses private pub gem to work, and its run ok on localhost, but not when I deploy it to heroku. I think that problem which is HTTPS protocol on Heroku. I'm already tried almost everything to do it run on Heroku, but I did not find a solution yet. Someone already make the private pub run over HTTPS before?

The cert is trusted by browser. I'm testing on Opera and Chrome. If I change to http on heroku, the file faye.js is blocked and do not loaded. When I run the thin server on heroku I get the error: "Sure you're not looking for /faye ?", And when I do not load the thin server by procfile I get a js error on browser when the chat is loaded: application-2563428….js:19064 GET myapp.herokuapp.com/faye.js

my setup is:

**private_pub.yml** (/config)

```
development:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
test:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
production:
  server: "https://my.app.com/faye"
  secret_token: "c2c373dd2d7b8d080311d4d32f9710a7c01ee627c30a75ec1143559b74a82c75"
  signature_expiration: 86400 # one day
```

**private_pub.ru** (/)

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "production")
run PrivatePub.faye_app
```

I'm already tried [this](https://webprogramming29.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/setup-privatepub-or-faye-on-heroku/) and [this](https://github.com/Hareramrai/fayeserver) without success. My tutorial reference is [this](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails).

A guy was success at [here](https://github.com/sahil290791/discussions_app), but I still have not figured out how.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you assume the heroic port for your app will always be `9292`?

Comment: I'm already tried remove it

Comment: I'm already remove it.

Comment: Removing it might not change the way the Faye server is set up. Faye might still be listening on port `9292` even though that port isn't open to the public (Heroku doesn't route to that port). The Heroku dyno only routes traffic to one port, you should have all communication listen on the same port.

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but this do not fix my problem.

Comment: Are you [using `Faye` as middleware](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets#using-with-rails)?

Comment: Yes, and I'm already tried the configs for ssl on documentation: https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby

Comment: Do you have a signed certificate (one that is trusted by the OS)? If not, are you testing with Safari (even if you click trust with safari, safari doesn't trust and doesn't connect to Websockets)? What happens if you use `server: "http://...` instead of `server: "https://...` (the path is changed to `wss://` internally, so maybe it's changed to `wsss://`)? Did you look at the browser console for errors or warnings?

Comment: Yes, the cert is trusted by browser. I'm testing on Opera and Chrome. If I change to http on heroku, the file faye.js is blocked and do not load. When I run the thin server on heroku I get the error: "Sure you're not looking for /faye ?", And when I do not load the thin server by procfile I get a js error on browser when the chat is loaded: application-2563428….js:19064 GET https://myapp.herokuapp.com/faye.js

Comment: Could you edit the question to add all the information in these comments, this will give people with experience the chance to help you. Especially, if you could provide detailed error logs and messages, that would help. At the moment, the question doesn't have enough details to track down the issue.

Comment: P.S.  the `private_pub.ru` is an application, exactly as much as Rails is an application. My humble guess is that both Rails and Faye (`private_pub.ru`) compete on the port assigned by Heroku, meaning only one of them runs at any given startup (Probably Rails) while the other fails to start up (due to the port being unavailable). If both start, they require two dynos and probably two domain names (or subdomain names) etc'